# Google app engine: maven or eclipse google plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I'm new to Google App Engine. To use Java App Engine, there are two options provided by Google: create a Maven project, or non-maven project backed by Eclipse Google Plugin. According to the doc, Eclipse version is easier. So should I go ahead with Eclipse? But I have seen lots of posts about maven. Could anyone comment what the pro/cons of using Maven are.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although you might want to try our first with the Eclipse plugin, Maven is the way to go in the long run because :

- It is designed to enable collaboration between developers, ensuring everyone uses the same libraries and the same build process
- It works with any serious Java IDEA, not only Eclipse. If you or the people you work with use IntelliJ, Netbeans or anything else Maven will help harmonize everything
- It allows you to do [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) . Especially since now this comes [bundled with App Engine via push-to-deploy](https://developers.google.com/cloud/devtools/repo/push-to-deploy). Push-to-deploy is great because it allows you to do debugging in production from the admin console. But you need to use Maven for it to work.

In conclusion, use the Eclipse plugin for your first quick-and-dirty tutorial or test project. But then learn Maven to make a real project.